Cyclic module decomposition theorems over Quasi-Frobenius (QF) rings
I remember reading somewhere that a ring $R$ is QF if every cyclic $R$-module is a direct sum of a projective module and a module $D$, but I forgot what the properties of $D$ are. This is very important to me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I found a resource with a necessary condition that says *Every module over a QF ring is a direct sum of a projective module and a small module" but I did not find a sufficient condition to say $R$ is QF.  What you are describing sounds very familiar though.

@rschwieb I found the answer in the paper: "On small and cosmall modules". The inverse also holds.

If that's "the answer" then I'll undelete the one I wrote.  At the time it seemed like it might not be what you're looking for.

@rschwieb I mean you are correct. It stated that: The following are equivalent for a ring R.
(a) R is a QF ring.
(b) Every module is a direct sum of a projective module and a small module.
(c) Every module is a direct sum of an injective module and a cosmall module.

There might very well be more than one answer...
One source I found says

Rayar, Mary. Small and cosmall modules. Indiana University, 1971.

Proves that for a quasi-Frobenius ring, every module is the direct sum of an injective module and a small module (but the injectives and projectives coincide, so...)
